# Chrome-cast Remote Debugger allow unauthenticated sources always load

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, chromecast

Hi I'm currently developing for Chromecast, and everytime I make a change chromecast gives me a new session for debugging in chrome devtools.

Arter getting into CHROMECAST-IP:9222
there's a link that takes me to a url like the following 
https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_rev/{weird token}/inspector.html?ws={CHROMECASTIP}:9222>/devtools/page/{session}

And then Chrome Dev Tools load , and I get this.

[image]

I'm trying to make the dev process easier, so is there a way to always allow this scripts always load without getting this dialog ?

Comment: Not sure if there is an easier way but upon checking the solution about [Fix the error "This page is trying to load scripts from unauthenticated sources"](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1342714?hl=en), the only suggestion is by clicking *Load unsafe script*. Chrome will refresh the page and load its content, including any insecure content.

Comment: Yeah I've been doing that and is becoming kinda of frustrating , it's because of the mixed content http/https and I changed my host to be https and somehow still loading my scripts with http